# Convert.FromBase64String acting weird

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have following code

```
String[] recievedChunks = received_data.Split('|');
String sb = "";

foreach (String chunck in recievedChunks)
{
    sb+=(Cryptography.RSA.decrypt(globals.serverPrivateKey, chunck));
}

//sb = H4sIAAAAAAAAAG2MywrCQAxF/yXrUqjuulMXUlwI/kGcibU4L5IUkdJ/N1oXCq4mc+69ZwIXUARayNzXifSaRWuXY8Tkpd6TdkrxRFJyEoIKPpENetLBMmPvp53+qjwq1t3S8ySOh6JDTtZqVusX41zwHAjaCwYhk5m7qSBhNAab7c5KhQdnv6axQBTdbVkojzZQRk8/4FHsXlVwJ+Qv91wBk4xBzXs8wPwEOn1v+/wAAAA=

Debug.Log("dodecrypt" + sb);

Debug.Log(Convert.FromBase64String("H4sIAAAAAAAAAG2MywrCQAxF/yXrUqjuulMXUlwI/kGcibU4L5IUkdJ/N1oXCq4mc+69ZwIXUARayNzXifSaRWuXY8Tkpd6TdkrxRFJyEoIKPpENetLBMmPvp53+qjwq1t3S8ySOh6JDTtZqVusX41zwHAjaCwYhk5m7qSBhNAab7c5KhQdnv6axQBTdbVkojzZQRk8/4FHsXlVwJ+Qv91wBk4xBzXs8wPwEOn1v+/wAAAA="));

Debug.Log(Convert.FromBase64String(sb));
```

Last line is giving me error:

> FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters.
>   Any ideas?

Debug output

```
dodecrypt H4sIAAAAAAAAAG2MywrCQAxF/yXrUqjuulMXUlwI/kGcibU4L5IUkdJ/N1oXCq4mc+69ZwIXUARayNzXifSaRWuXY8Tkpd6TdkrxRFJyEoIKPpENetLBMmPvp53+qjwq1t3S8ySOh6JDTtZqVusX41zwHAjaCwYhk5m7qSBhNAab7c5KhQdnv6axQBTdbVkojzZQRk8/4FHsXlVwJ+Qv91wBk4xBzXs8wPwEOn1v+/wAAAA=
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
GameClient:writeSocketReturnCrypted(String) (at 
Assets/Src/Networking/GameClient.cs:221)
Assets.Src.Networking.Commands.GetItem.GetItem:getItem(Int32) (at 
Assets/Src/Networking/Commands/GetItem/GetItem.cs:15)
GameClient:Update() (at Assets/Src/Networking/GameClient.cs:76)

System.Byte[]
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)

FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a 
non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal 
character among the padding characters.
```

Comment: What's the value of sb at the point the exception is thrown?

Comment: `H4sIAAAAAAAAAG2MywrCQAxF/yXrUqjuulMXUlwI/kGcibU4L5IUkdJ/N1oXCq4mc+69ZwIXUARayNzXifSaRWuXY8Tkpd6TdkrxRFJyEoIKPpENetLBMmPvp53+qjwq1t3S8ySOh6JDTtZqVusX41zwHAjaCwYhk5m7qSBhNAab7c5KhQdnv6axQBTdbVkojzZQRk8/4FHsXlVwJ+Qv91wBk4xBzXs8wPwEOn1v+/wAAAA=`

Comment: `sb+=` you can't just decrypt it in chunks and then concat the base64 encoded chunks, that's not how base64 works. (This might coincidentially work in 20% of all cases but don't rely on it)

Comment: In general encryption of data, especially data larger than can be encrypted in one RSA operation by splitting into "chunks" is not the preferred and general solution. The preferred solution is [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) where the data is encrypted with a symmetric algorithm (such as AES), that symmetric key is encrypted with an asymmetric algorithm (RSA in this case) and the two encryptions are bundled together.

Comment: Yes, i agree, but symmetric algorithm encryption (tried Blowfish) is pain if you have Java server and unity(.net) client

Comment: Ah, developer pain wins over generally accepted methods. Which choice would a professional make? (Don't use Blowfish, even the author of Blowfish uses AES.) Further, RSA is orders of magnitude slower than AES.

Answer (score 0):

The base 64 encoded string is evaluated in pairs of 4. You have to provide an amount of characters dividable by 4. Adding padding characters (`=`) at the end will do:

```
byte[] b = Convert.FromBase64String("H4...==");
```

Another problem is that you are reading in chunks. Always make sure you end up with the right amount of characters per chunk, or else your program will not decode correctly.

Comment: But why does 
`Debug.Log(Convert.FromBase64String("H4sIAAAAAAAAAG2MywrCQAxF/yXrUqjuulMXUlwI/kGcibU4L5IUkdJ/N1oXCq4mc+69ZwIXUARayNzXifSaRWuXY8Tkpd6TdkrxRFJyEoIKPpENetLBMmPvp53+qjwq1t3S8ySOh6JDTtZqVusX41zwHAjaCwYhk5m7qSBhNAab7c5KhQdnv6axQBTdbVkojzZQRk8/4FHsXlVwJ+Qv91wBk4xBzXs8wPwEOn1v+/wAAAA="));`

work?

Comment: It does work here. Are you sure the strings are the same?

Comment: Added debug output to post

Comment: In my answer there are two padding characters. In your debug output still one.

Comment: @MartinKõrvel it doesn't work... the exception you've posted is not thrown from the last line as you've stated, but from the second `Debug.Log`.

Comment: I did not include debug output for second Debug.Log

Added in post now.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your code, you have a `|` delimited collection of base-64 encoded chunks of RSA encrypted data. The way your input is put together could have been built any number of ways, since the decryption works but the decoding fails, I'm guessing you do it kind of like this:

1. Base64 Encode all of your data
2. Split the (encoded) data into chunks
3. Encrypt each chunk
4. Join the chunks with `|`

Your decrypt/decode process however doesn't match this sequence:

1. Split the blocks by `|`
2. Decrypt the block
3. Concat the decrypted base64 blocks together
4. Decode the resulting string.

Make sure the decrypting/decoding process does the same as your encrypting/encoding process but in **reverse order**. Right now you probably have a couple of `=`s in the middle of `sb`, which is why it works for a single chunk (the second Log) but not the entire concated base64 string (because it's invalid - you can't just arbitrarily join base64 encoded strings).

Comment: Yes, this is what am i doing. base64 in sb in actually gzipped string. Tested with http://www.txtwizard.net/compression If you put provided base64 string there, it works.

Comment: @MartinKõrvel You seem to do a lot of unnecessary additional steps then - why base64 encode the gzip and why split the result, encode it separately and then join it with `|`?

Comment: I am using RSA 2048 bit keys. Thus i can encrypt only 211 bytes of data.

Comment: Reference https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33434/rsa-maximum-bytes-to-encrypt-comparison-to-aes-in-terms-of-security

Comment: Oh, wait, you are encrypting all of your data with RSA? Not just the Key for your actual encryption? Don't do that - with larger amounts of data you will actually have **less** security and be vulnerable to repetition attacks. If you need an easy fix, encrypt the data with a random key for a block or stream cypher of your choice (e.g. Triple DES, AES, or something EC based) and encrypt **that** with RSA.

Comment: If you want to stick with what you have - base64 decode each block and **then** join the resulting byte arrays instead. (e.g. with a `List<byte>`, `AddRange` and `ToArray`)

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer Triple DES is a poor choice that should mot be used in new work. EC based has the same problem as RSA but worse because of smaller keys.

Comment: @zaph Is it? I was not aware of that, thanks for the info.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer 3DES has an effective security of 112-bits, see [Security comparsion of 3DES and AES](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26179/security-comparsion-of-3des-and-aes) for more information.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer  EC (Eliptic Curve) encryption is an asymmetric method with much smaller keys than RSA and also has a limitation that the data must be smaller than the key. RSA keys are getting rather large with 2048-bits being a reasonably secure length, EC provided the same security level with a 168-bit to 224-bit key, see [ECC vs RSA: key sizes?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/25578/4747) and is primarily used to create symmetric keys and with ECDH for exchange of symmetric keys.